# How to avoid 'SettingWithCopyWarning' without using 'loc'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have read many postings about 'SettingWithCopyWarning'. Using 'loc' seems to be the most straightforward way to avoid this warning.

However, it is hard to use `loc` when the index is `DatetimeIndex` as like `df` in the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=6), columns=['a', 'b'])
df['c'] = 10 
print(df)

                              a    b   c
2022-02-16 15:31:09.927441  NaN  NaN  10
2022-02-17 15:31:09.927441  NaN  NaN  10
2022-02-18 15:31:09.927441  NaN  NaN  10
2022-02-19 15:31:09.927441  NaN  NaN  10
2022-02-20 15:31:09.927441  NaN  NaN  10
2022-02-21 15:31:09.927441  NaN  NaN  10
```

In this situation, I am using `df.loc[df.index==df.index[1],'a'] = 10` as recommended by many postings. However, typing `df.index==df.index[1]` every time is cumbersome.

Sp, I am wondering if there is a simple way to index such a `df` with an index number and column name. For example, `df['a'][1]=10` is simple and intuitive, but it returns the 'SettingWithCopyWarning' warning.

Thank you for any comment in advance.

Comment: `df.iloc` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc('a')]=10
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could define a wrapper to do the job for you:

```
def get(df,idx,col,val=None):
    if not isinstance(idx, list):
        idx = [idx]
    if val:
        df.loc[df.index.isin(df.index[idx]), col] = val
    else:
        return df.loc[df.index.isin(df.index[idx]), col]

# getting value
get(df,1,'a')
# 2022-02-17 04:58:58.655186    10
# Freq: D, Name: a, dtype: object

# setting value(s) in place
get(df,1,'a',10)
get(df,[3,4],['a','b'],99)
```

Updated DF:

```
                              a    b   c
2022-02-16 04:58:58.655186  NaN  NaN  10
2022-02-17 04:58:58.655186   10  NaN  10
2022-02-18 04:58:58.655186  NaN  NaN  10
2022-02-19 04:58:58.655186   99   99  10
2022-02-20 04:58:58.655186   99   99  10
2022-02-21 04:58:58.655186  NaN  NaN  10
```